# response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OperationResponse<T>> vs response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>() what is the different?

Tags: c#, api, http, httpresponsemessage

I saw code like below

May I know what is the different and when I show use

- response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OperationResponse> and return return operationResponse.SuccessResponse;
- response.Content.ReadAsAsync() and return return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync();

```
private async Task<T> ReadOperationResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
        where T : class
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var rawContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawContent))
                    throw new ApiException(rawContent);

                var rawContentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                    throw new ApiException(rawContentStream.ToString());
            }

            var operationResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<OperationResponse<T>>();
            if (!operationResponse.HasSucceeded)
                throw new ApiException(operationResponse.ErrorResponse.Message);

            return operationResponse.SuccessResponse;
        }
```

```
private async Task<T> ReadResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
        where T : class
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new ApiException(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
        }
```

Try to understand what is the differnt and when to use either one

***No worries. I think I found the answer. We have an object try to store more information

```
    public class OperationResponse<T> : IOperationResponse<T> where T : class
{
    public bool HasSucceeded { get; set; }

    public ErrorResponse ErrorResponse { get; set; }

    public T SuccessResponse { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the difference between the first and the second code block? The first code block does not make much sense to me.

Comment: @SebastianS. I think I know why now. We have an object that try to store more information